# Nexus 5x No Wifi. Default MAC 02-00-00-00-00-00 change attempt

Tags: wi-fi, 7.0-nougat, mobile-network, nexus-5x, mac-address

So I bought new Nexus 5x with android 6.0 and everything worked fine, but when I updated to 7.1.2 suddenly wifi stoped working. (It seeks for wifi networks forever). When I go to settings I can see MAC adress which is default one 02:00:00:00:00:00. I've noticed that its common problem for phone like Nexus 5, 5x 6p and Pixels but all solutions I could find just failed.

**What i have tried:**

first simplest solutions they gave like pulling off SIM card, turning off phone, charging battery to 100%. - Failed

Then i was trying to install other versions of Nougath 7, 7.1 , 7.1.2. Switching back to Android 6 makes wifi running again.

Some people said that changing MAC adress resolved issue, so firstly I have rooted my phone. Then I have tried to use some external programs for changing MAC but they didint worked.

**Problem**

I am trying to change MAC manualy. I did it few times on other linux/windows machines with no issue.

when i check for avalible network interfaces throught 
*ifconfig*
it outputs

```
bullhead:/ $ ifconfig
rmnet_ipa0 Link encap:UNSPEC
      UP RUNNING  MTU:2000  Metric:1
      RX packets:843 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1129 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:563887 TX bytes:210944

dummy0    Link encap:UNSPEC
      inet6 addr: fe80::78e6:16ff:fe96:3cf7/64 Scope: Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 TX bytes:210

rmnet_data0 Link encap:UNSPEC
      inet addr:10.156.9.217  Mask:255.255.255.252
      inet6 addr: fe80::53e3:f4d7:6ca9:be5e/64 Scope: Link
      UP RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:843 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1129 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:568878 TX bytes:210944

lo        Link encap:UNSPEC
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope: Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 TX bytes:0
```

there is no *eth0* interface nor *wlan0*. All of those interfaces does not have mac assigned. As I have tested *rmnet_ipa0* and *rmnet_data0* are probably for mobile connection (ifconfig (rm..) down makes mobile connection off.
So my question is how do I find network interface for wifi so I can try digging in it.

Thanks!

Comment: If nothing works, you could try flashing the latest factory image. [7.1.2]

Comment: I did. Same issue

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/help/qa-wifi-stuck-mac-020000000000-g2-g3-g4-t3452133   Seems to be a hardware issue. You could try sending it to the manufacturer if it's still under warranty

Comment: Strange thing. But if it was a hardware problem - wifi on android 6 would not run either right? But it works

Comment: what is your fastboot critical unlock state?

Answer (score 0):

Install lineageos and see if it works
As I see, vendor firmwares are quite glitchy on nexus phones (I have nexus 5 (Hammerhead, non-X) and vendor android 6 worked with freezes while latest lineageos nightly works perfectly (though without gapps))